# No encuentro el archivo Syslog.conf en Centos 7

Tags: linux, unix, centos7

Soy principiante en el mundo de linux, actualmente estoy usando Centos 7, lo que requiero es manejar los mensajes del sistema con syslogd, a lo cual despues de ver varias paginas veo que hay que ubicar un archivo llamado syslog.conf, pero no lo encuentro en la carpeta /etc donde deberia estar supuestamente.

El unico que encuentro es el rsyslog.conf a lo cual no se si sea el mismo. Tambien tengo duda en donde ingresar los comandos como el *emerg  /var/messages, es dentro de ese archivo o donde se ingresa para ejecutar esa instruccion?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo `Syslog` es un protocolo(ver protocolo [aquí](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424)) para el de registro y monitoreo de mensajes. Hay servicios como Syslog, Syslog-ng, Rsyslog que utilizan el protocolo syslog, son una bitácora donde el sistema y las diferentes aplicaciones reportan sus acciones. se puede realizar depuración y automatización dependiendo del **nivel de severidad** o **estados**, los niveles son:

1. **Emergencia**, Posee como valor 0, indica que el sistema es inutilizable; un estado de pánico.
2. **Alerta**, Posee como valor 1, indica que sucede una situación que debe tener atención de inmediato.
3. **Critico**, posee como valor 2, indica un estado de error que no pudo ser solucionado por el sistema, necesita asistencia manual.
4. **Error**, posee como valor 3, indica que ocurrió error, un ejemplo podría ser un error en la conexión de red.
5. **Peligro**, posee como valor 4, indica un estado de peligro, condiciones que son peligrosas y que hay que tener en cuenta para evitar posibles errores o problemas de seguridad.
6. **Noticia**, posee como valor 5, indica que ocurrió una condición que aunque es normal puede llegar a ser importante.
7. **Información**, posee como valor 6, indica un estado de información.
8. **Debug**, posee como valor 7, este estado se utiliza para depurar el sistema, se muestra absolutamente todo los estados del sistema, ademas de estados aún de mas bajo nivel, utilizado para encontrar fallas y comportamientos indeseados en el sistema.

Más información [aquí](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424#section-6.2.1)

Ahora los sistemas que utilizan como gestor de demonios a `SystemD`, reemplazaron al *servicio* Syslog por `JournalD`, que hace parte del amo y señor todo poderoso `SystemD`, pero se puede utilizar sin problemas los dos servicios.

Principalmente una de las ventajas de utilizar el servicio `Syslog` es que puedes automatizar la bitácora, que te envíe mensajes a tu correo de pendiendo del nivel de severidad, si ocurre un estado critico en tu sistema pues que te lo envíe a tu correo, es una de las muchas ventajas, desconozco si `journalD` permite hacer esto o no.

Según la Wiki de [Gentoo](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Rsyslog), RSyslog es:

> Rsyslog es un software de código abierto que se utiliza en los sistemas informáticos UNIX y Unix-Like para reenviar mensajes de registro en una red IP. Implementa el protocolo syslog básico, lo amplía con filtrado basado en contenido, capacidades de filtrado enriquecedoras, opciones de configuración flexibles y agrega características importantes como el uso de TCP para el transporte.

---

**EDITADO 1**

Agrego información porque considero que la respuesta se quedaba algo corta.

Imagen sacada de su [página oficial](http://www.rsyslog.com/)
[image: Funcionamiento de RSyslog]

La siguiente información es en base a la [documentación oficial](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/) de RSyslog.

## Instalación

La instalación de RSyslog es bastante sencilla desde los repositorios, en sistemas CentOS viene por defecto así que no creo que es necesario, comprueba si lo tienes instalado, si no, procede se la siguiente manera como administrador:

```
yum install rsyslog
```

En sistemas donde extrañamente no tiene el paquete en sus repositorios, o la versión que poseen esta desactualizada, puedes conseguir información de como instalar su paquete manualmente [aquí](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/installation/packages.html).

## Configuración

El servicio `RSyslog` se puede configurar por medio del archivo `/etc/rsyslog.conf`. También se puede configurar de manera interactiva utilizando [rsyslog configuration builder tool](http://www.rsyslog.com/rsyslog-configuration-builder/).

RSyslog tiene mejoras sobre Syslog estándar, aunque el archivo de configuración es compatible entre los diferentes servicios, RSyslog posee características agregadas por lo que lógicamente su archivo de configuración sera mas extenso, pero debería poder funcionar con un archivo de configuración syslog.conf estándar. Esto es útil cuando se esta migrando de un servicio a otro.

Como existen muchísimas configuraciones que se le pueden aplicar a RSyslog, me saltara muchísimas, por no decir casi todas, e iré a lo básico, puedes mirar sus diferentes configuraciones [aquí](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/index.html).

### Formatos

RSyslog se puede configurar utilizando 3 formatos:

- **Básico**: anteriormente conocido como el formato *sysklogd*, este formato es el que se utiliza para lo básico, como configuraciones en una sola línea. Se remota al formato syslog.conf original.
- **Avanzado**: anteriormente conocido como *RainerScript*, este formado se encuentra desde rsyslog versión 6, y es su formato actual de configuración. Es mas preciso en configuraciones avanzadas que se necesita mas de una línea.
- **Herencia Obsoleta**: anteriormente conocido como formato heredado, este formato es exactamente lo su nombre indica, es obsoleto, y no debe utilizarse en ninguna de sus configuraciones. Es un formato de configuración de sus primeras versiones, utilizado hasta la versión 5.

### Formato básico

Solo explicare este formato, ya que es el utilizado para las configuraciones básicas de RSyslog.

Este formato se utiliza para configurar el archivo estándar syslog.conf, el cual es compatible con RSyslog. Cada regla consta de dos campos, un campo *selector* y un campo de *acción*, y estos campos están separados por espacios o pestañas. El campo *selector* especifica un pátron de *instalación*([Facility](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Rsyslog#Facility)) y prioridades que pertenecen a la acción especificada.

Las líneas comienzan con una marca de almohadilla("#") y las líneas vacías pues se ignoran.

#### Selectores

El campo selector consta de dos partes, una instalación(facility) y una prioridad, separadas por un punto("."). Ambas partes no distinguen entra mayúsculas y minúsculas.

La instalación(facility) especifica el subsistema que produjo el mensaje.

La prioridad es una de las siguientes palabras clave en orden ascendente: *debug*, *info*, *notice*, *warning*, *warn*( lo mismo que *warning*). Las palabras clave *warn*, *error*, *panic* están en desuso y ya no se debe utilizar. En si la prioridad define la gravedad del mensaje. Tenga en cuenta que como su nombre lo indica, son prioridades, así que hay prioridades mas altas y mas bajas, al seleccionar una prioridad baja, todas las prioridades que estén por encima de ella se seleccionaran también(a menos que se indique lo contrario).

Agregándole que ademas de los nombres mencionados, también se comprende que un asterisco("*") representa a **todas** las instalaciones o todas las prioridades, según donde se utilice, el nombre clave *none* significa ninguna prioridad o instalación.

Se puede especificar múltiples instalaciones para un patrón de prioridad único en una declaración usando el operador de coma(",") para separar las instalaciones. También se puede especificar múltiples selectores para una sola acción usando el punto y coma(";").

Se puede proceder a cada prioridad con un signo de igual("=") para especificar que **solo** se debe referir a esa prioridad y no a todas las prioridades por encima de esta. Se pueden indicar también con un signo de exclamación("!"), para que esa prioridad sea ignorada.

#### Ejemplos

```
# Store critical stuff in critical # *.=crit;kern.none /var/adm/critical
```

Esta regla almacenará todos los mensajes de prioridad critica(crit) en el archivo `/var/adm/critical`, con la excepción de cualquier mensaje del kernel.

```
# Kernel messages are stored in the kernel file, # critical messages and higher ones also go # to another host and to the console # kern.* /var/adm/kernel kern.crit @finlandia kern.crit /dev/console kern.info;kern.!err /var/adm/kernel-info
```

Hay varias instrucciones en una sola línea, la primera regla dice mensajes del kernel con cualquier prioridad se guarden en el archivo `/var/adm/kernel`.

La segunda instrucción dirige todos los mensajes del kernel con prioridad crit y superior a un host remoto llamado finlandia.

La tercera instrucción dirige los mensajes del kernel con prioridad crit y superior a una consola.

La cuarta instrucción dirige todos los mensajes del kernel con prioridades desde info hasta warning al archivo `/var/adm/kernel-info`.

```
# Write all mail related logs to a file # mail.*;mail.!=info /var/adm/mail
```

Esto almacenara en el archivo `/var/adm/mail` todo los mensajes que vienen de las instalación de correo con cualquier prioridad, excepto la prioridad info.

```
*.* @finlandia
```

Esta regla dirige todo los mensajes de todas las instalaciones y todas la prioridades a un servidor remoto llamado finlandia.

---

Está información fue sacada de la [documentación oficial](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/index.html) de RSyslog versión 8 y el estándar Syslog que puedes encontrarlo [aquí](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5424).